# Getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() by using &

Tags: php, loops, cookies, pass-by-reference

I am trying to re-edit cookie value.

When I don't use `&$prod`, it doesn't change the array value.

When I use `&$prod`, it changes the array but I get:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Is there any other way to update existing array or why am I getting this error?

```
$existingCookie = Cookie::get($cookie);
$arr = json_decode($existingCookie, true);
foreach ($arr as &$prod) {
    if($productId === $prod["pid"]) {
        if($prod["pqty"]!=$productQty){
            $prod["pqty"] = $productQty;
            $arr = json_encode($arr);
            Cookie::put($cookie, $arr, Config::get('cart/cookie_expiry'));
            echo var_dump($arr) . ' - '.$prod["pqty"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with `print_r($arr)`

Comment: You are modifying $arr array during the loop. That's totally wrong...

Comment: @u_mulder Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 2
            [pqty] => 3
        )

)

Comment: Previous comment explains what is wrong. Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to repair the whole `$arr` and then after looping, update the cookie just once.  This logically direct approach also eliminates the error as well.

The reason that you are getting the error is because you are using `&` in your foreach expression AND writing `$arr = json_encode($arr);` inside your loop.  The loop is not iterating a "copy" of the input array (as is the default), it is iterating the input array itself because of `&$prod`.  After the two conditions are satisfied, `$arr` is converted a json string and the foreach loop chokes on it.

```
$arr=json_decode(Cookie::get($cookie), true);
foreach($arr as &$prod){
    if($prod["pid"]===$productId && $prod["pqty"]!==$productQty){
        $prod["pqty"]=$productQty;
    }
}
Cookie::put($cookie, json_encode($arr), Config::get('cart/cookie_expiry'));
```

Comment: Is this correct @u_mulder ? I don't think I get what you were getting at (and that is stripping my confidence)

Comment: I did it already but thanks. Its not one loop there are more parent loops so why shouldn't I update array through loop?

Comment: @Stupid My answer still yields the error on `foreach()`?  I think there is something that you aren't telling us.

Comment: @Stupid If my answer doesn't solve the issue, we are going to need to see more code.  If you have more loops, are you sure we are addressing the correct loop?  Please post more of your code.

Comment: I am sending post data via ajax as array, where I loop through array to change existing cookie array with new values from post data array. If this make any sense. My code worked as well it changed array but besides that I got error. By your answer it do same without error.

Comment: IIt did but I asked you why it did, why I need it outside of for loop?

Comment: @Stupid Sorry, I've updated my answer to explain.  Here is a demo link: https://3v4l.org/8Gfgt